# Referencing Non-Decision/Non-Optimization Variables in AnyLogic MultiObjective Optimization

Tags: optimization, anylogic

TLDR: Looking to pull values of non-decision variables from OptQuest solution or find an viable work around for obtaining this information.

I'm currently running a weighted multi-objective optimization (custom) experiment in AnyLogic that deals with the profit of a manufacturer, distributor and retailer in a distribution channel.
My decision variables are the reorder points (r) and the reorder quantities (Q) for each of these members. My objectives are the profit of the channel (root.MultObjs) and the profit of the retailer (root.RObj).

```
try {
    // Create Engine, initialize random number generator:
    Engine engine = createEngine();
    engine.setStartTime(0.0);
    engine.setTimeUnit(DAY);
    // Set stop time:
    engine.setStopTime( 365 );

    // ***Create optimization variable***   
    
    
    final COptQuestDiscreteVariable Rr = new COptQuestDiscreteVariable();
    Rr.SetLowerBound(100);
    Rr.SetUpperBound(3000);
    Rr.SetStepSize(100);
    final COptQuestDiscreteVariable RQ = new COptQuestDiscreteVariable();
    RQ.SetLowerBound(100);
    RQ.SetUpperBound(3000);
    RQ.SetStepSize(100);
    final COptQuestDiscreteVariable Dr = new COptQuestDiscreteVariable();
    Dr.SetLowerBound(100);
    Dr.SetUpperBound(10000);
    Dr.SetStepSize(100);
    final COptQuestDiscreteVariable DQ = new COptQuestDiscreteVariable();
    DQ.SetLowerBound(100);
    DQ.SetUpperBound(10000);
    DQ.SetStepSize(100);
    final COptQuestDiscreteVariable Mr = new COptQuestDiscreteVariable();
    Mr.SetLowerBound(100);
    Mr.SetUpperBound(15000);
    Mr.SetStepSize(100);
    final COptQuestDiscreteVariable MQ = new COptQuestDiscreteVariable();
    MQ.SetLowerBound(100);
    MQ.SetUpperBound(15000);
    MQ.SetStepSize(100);
    
    
    // add parameters
    
    final COptQuestContinuousVariable R_Inv = new COptQuestContinuousVariable();

    // ***Create objectives***
    final COptQuestObjective obj1 = new COptQuestUserControlledObjective(); //Retailer
    obj1.SetMaximize();
    final COptQuestObjective obj2 = new COptQuestUserControlledObjective(); //Chain
    obj2.SetMaximize();
    
    
    //weighted coefficients starts here

    final COptQuestWeightedMultiObjective weightedMultiObjective = new COptQuestWeightedMultiObjective();
    weightedMultiObjective.AddObjective(obj1,0);
    weightedMultiObjective.AddObjective(obj2,1);
        
    //set requirements
    COptQuestUpperRequirement ReqROverstock= new COptQuestUpperRequirement(0);
    COptQuestUpperRequirement ReqDOverstock= new COptQuestUpperRequirement(0);
    COptQuestUpperRequirement ReqMOverstock= new COptQuestUpperRequirement(0);
        
    // Create optimization engine
    final COptQuestOptimization opt = ExperimentOptimization.createOptimization(engine, new OptimizationCallback() 
    {
    
        @Override
        public void evaluate(COptQuestOptimization optimization,
                COptQuestSolution solution, Engine engine) 
        {
                
            // Create new root object:
            Main root = new Main( engine, null, null );
    
            // Setup parameters of root object here
                
            //set default values of vars
            root.setParametersToDefaultValues();
            
            //set decision variables
            //***left side model*** ***right side*** optimization
            root.Rr = (int)solution.GetVariableValue(Rr);
            root.RQ = (int)solution.GetVariableValue(RQ);
            root.Dr = (int)solution.GetVariableValue(Dr);
            root.DQ = (int)solution.GetVariableValue(DQ);
            root.Mr = (int)solution.GetVariableValue(Mr);
            root.MQ = (int)solution.GetVariableValue(MQ);
            
        
            
            // Prepare Engine for simulation:
            root.getDefaultRandomGenerator().setSeed(1);
            engine.start( root );
            
            // Start simulation in fast mode:
            engine.runFast();
            // Process results of simulation here
            
            //***left side method expression*** ***right side model objective****
            solution.SetObjectiveValue( obj1, root.RObj );
            solution.SetObjectiveValue( obj2, root.MultObjs );

            
            //set requirements here 
            solution.SetRequirementValue(ReqROverstock,root.ROverstock);
            solution.SetRequirementValue(ReqDOverstock,root.DOverstock);
            solution.SetRequirementValue(ReqMOverstock,root.MOverstock);
        
            // Destroy the model:
            engine.stop();
        }
            
    });
    
        
        // ***Setup optimization engine***
        
        //add decision variables
        opt.AddVariable(Rr);
        opt.AddVariable(RQ); 
        opt.AddVariable(Dr);
        opt.AddVariable(DQ); 
        opt.AddVariable(Mr);
        opt.AddVariable(MQ); 
        

        // add constraints 
        opt.AddRequirement(ReqROverstock);
        opt.AddRequirement(ReqDOverstock);
        opt.AddRequirement(ReqMOverstock);
        
        // add objective
        opt.AddObjective(weightedMultiObjective);

        
        // Set the number of iterations to run
        opt.SetMaximumIterations(500);
        
        // Perform optimization
        opt.Optimize();
        
    //setup for printout
    traceln(" Lambda : Param Rr : Param RQ : Param Dr : Param DQ : Param Mr : Param MQ: :    Best obj1(R)   :   Best obj2(Chain)   :  DProfit : MProfit : feasible?");
    traceln("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        
        double nLambda=10; //sets resolution of weighted multi-objective search
        for (int i=0; i <=nLambda; i++)
        {
            double lweight=i/nLambda;
            weightedMultiObjective.SetObjectiveCoefficient(obj1, lweight);
            weightedMultiObjective.SetObjectiveCoefficient(obj2, (1- lweight));
            
            opt.Recalculate();

            COptQuestSolution bestSolution = opt.GetBestSolution(); 
            //COptQuestSolution currentSolution=opt.GetIterationSolution(500);
            
            // Output results
            traceln(String.format("  %1.2f : %7.2f : %8.2f : %8.2f : %8.2f : %8.2f : %8.2f : %8.2f : %8.2f : %8.2f : %8.2f : %8s",
            lweight, bestSolution.GetVariableValue(Rr),bestSolution.GetVariableValue(RQ), 
            bestSolution.GetVariableValue(Dr),bestSolution.GetVariableValue(DQ),,
            bestSolution.GetVariableValue(Mr),bestSolution.GetVariableValue(MQ),
            
            bestSolution.GetObjectiveValue(obj1),
            bestSolution.GetObjectiveValue(obj2), 
            null,
            null,
            bestSolution.IsFeasible()));

        }
} 

catch (COptQuestException e) {
    traceln(e.Description());
}
```

I picked my way through the OptQuest documentation and managed to get an executable model that prints my decision variables and the objectives at the end of the experiment. What I'd really like to do is to pull instances of the non-decision variables (root.RBackOrderCost, root.RCarryingCost) from the optimal solution and include these in the output.  The problem that I’m running into is that the OptQuestSolution Class only seem to be concerned with the input of decision variables and the out of objectives,  and by the time we’ve figured those out, the engine has already been destroyed, so I can’t just pull a value from root.
I threw a few hail-Marys to no avail:

1. I tried to create a dummy decision variable (even a dummy objective) to store values in this prior to the engine being destroyed, but this didn’t work.
2. I also tried storing values of variables from the simulation callback into an array outside of the callback. No luck there, either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to get `COptQuestSolution` to carry extra variables. The way I have done this before is by saving extra information before `root` object is destroyed. To do it:

1. create a `Map<Integer, Map<String, Double>> extraVars` outside `evaluate`
2. then populate `extraVars` inside `evaluate` method before call to `engine.stop()` using `solution.getIteration` as key

Comment: 1. Great idea!
2. Worked *perfectly*

Thank you so much!

Comment: Excellent. Can you please mark the question as 'answered'?